# CORS error, but data is fetched regardless

Tags: javascript, cors, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api

I have a generated React site I am hosting in an S3 bucket. One of my components attempts to fetch something when loaded:

```
require('isomorphic-fetch')
...

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`${url}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        users: res
      })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // do nothing
    })
}
```

The `url` I am fetching is an AWS API Gateway. I have enabled CORS there, via the dropdown, with no changes to the default configuration.

In my console, for both the remote site and locally during development, I see:

"Failed to load `url`: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." etc

However, in the Chrome Network tab, I can see the request and the response, with status 200, etc. In the console, my `console.log` and `this.setState` are never called, however.

I understand that CORS is a common pain point, and that many questions have touched on CORS. My question: Why does the response show no error in the Network tab, while simultaneously erroring in the console?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `` fetch(`${url}`) `` call returns a promise that resolves with a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), and that `Response` object provides [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods) that resolve with [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), [JSON data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), or a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob).

So to get the data you want, you need to do something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`${url}`)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text);
      this.setState({
        users: text
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // do nothing
    })
}
```

> Failed to load url: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." etc

That means the browser isn’t allowing your frontend code to access the response from the server, because the response doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

So in order for the above code to work, you’ll need to fix the server configuration on that server so that it sends the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

> However, in the Chrome Network tab, I can see the request and the response, with status 200, etc. In the console, my `console.log` and `this.setState` are never called, however.

That’s expected in the case where the server doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. In that case, the browser still gets the response — and that’s why you can see it in the devtools Network tab — but just because the browser gets the response doesn’t mean it will expose the response to your frontend JavaScript code.

The browser will only let your code access the response if it includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header; if the response doesn’t include that header, then the browser blocks your code from accessing it.

> My question: Why does the response show no error in the Network tab, while simultaneously erroring in the console?

For the reason outlined above. The browser itself runs into no error in getting the response. But your code hits an error because it’s trying to access an `res` object that’s not there; the browser hasn’t created that `res` object, because the browser isn’t exposing the response to your code.

Comment: "The browser itself runs into no error in getting the response. But your code runs into an error because it’s trying to access a response that’s not there — because the browser isn’t exposing the response to your code." This is exactly what I was looking for. I'd actually fixed the error itself shortly after posting but it was one of those big huge "Whyyy" fixes. Now I know. Thanks

Comment: _"because it’s trying to access a response that’s not there"_ this confuses me, as I'm getting a CORS error and response data at the same time (GET call).

Comment: Why is the server even sending the data when the origin is a mismatch. Why not simply block it? Isn't this a security lapse? I know it isn't but can't understand how or why?

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing the status 200 for the `OPTIONS` not the GET. There is a setting for CORS to handle legacy, so it won't confuse your client. I had to do that last time in a React app. Your error is that your CORS isn't configured properly (sorry, obviously). Chrome won't let your client tlak to the backend if it doesn't get the headers properly. Other browsers probably also, probably React also. It may be some kind of HTTP protocol if only one side has CORS enabled. Someone can correct me there. It's a similar security consideration as sending a request to HTTP from HTTPS. Chrome blocks it.

It looks to me like it's your backend. CORS isn't active or it would put that header on, and after that, you would see errors about origin mismatch in the frontend client.

In my experience, it's a 2-3 step combo, make sure `OPTIONS` don't send confusing signals to your client (look for settings to do with `200`). This is a config setting in your backend. Then, make sure the backend is configured to use CORS. You very specifically need to enter the origin hostname and port that the backend is to expect traffic from.

I could probably give better input if I see what languages and/or frameworks you are using besides React.

This is what you would do in Express JS and node for your Backend:

```
const cors = require('cors')

// note http or https
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://example.com:1337',
    //origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
    // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
}))
```

My last React app was detonating without optionsSuccessStatus by throwing success when it was fail.

To give you a little bit of imagery to work with, CORS is simple but finicky. It's a simple matter of alignment. Once your backend is configured to a) use CORS and b) know who to accept traffic from, it's done. Once your frontend is configured to handle this traffic, it's done. It's like aligning a square peg in a round hole until you get the config settings aligned.

Try using `Postman` to send some GET requests to the Backend. You can observe the headers from there.

Comment: The 200 I am seeing in the network tab is the same request that also successfully includes the data I am requesting. That can't be OPTIONS, can it?

Comment: Try maybe press F12 to open dev tools in the browser, then click on the Network tab at the top. You should see everything. You may see 204s being interpretted as 200.

Comment: "I could probably give better input if I see what languages and/or frameworks you are using besides React." It's the AWS API Gateway that handles CORS, etc. That then delegates to a Lambda function, however I don't think that is at issue here.

Comment: "Try maybe press F12 to open dev tools in the browser, then click on the Network tab at the top. You should see everything. You may see 204s being interpretted as 200." Wha? I am looking at the Network tab in Chrome now. I see the request headers, response headers, and response JSON—everything looks as it should. The only place I'd know I have an error is if I look in the console, or by the fact that `setState` is never called