# issue with flask-cors - blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular, flask, flask-cors

I'm a newbie in flask and angular please bear with me.

I've been stuck with an issue about CORS. I've applied different code fixes just to make it work. Now the error that I am getting is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard/clientscount/2019/2020' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I think the answer to my problem is from the answered question on this post: [Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298478/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesn-t-pass-acce), specifcally this code

```
if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    return
}
```

but this is in go language. I'm working in flask. my question is how do I make this in flask? also in the reference answer, it says to respond to the initial request but I'm not sure how to proceed with that one.

If you could point me in the right direction or docs, I'd gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

As the comments on the link describes, if you have setup CORS in your application and still has the problem, possible is because your application is calling a path that may differ from the path that you register.

example:

Flask url:
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/support-user/

Called url:
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/support-user

`Missing / at the end`

You can ensure that the problem is this if you see in your logs that flask redirect the request with 308

https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/257

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem, api path was incorrect compared to what was registered

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I was skeptical of this answer at first but it actually worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using blueprint. You have to wrap blueprint in cors too.

```
blueprint = Blueprint("foo", __name__, url_prefix="/api/bar")
CORS(blueprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help:

[How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

You have to first install flask-cors by running: `pip install -U flask-cors`

Then import CORS and Cors-origin as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
```