# Unable to run cors on flask app with blueprints

Tags: python, flask, cors

I am unable to get cors enabled on my app inside my flask app using the flask_cors package after I started using blueprints in my app. I have the following structure

```
app
  api
     __init__.py
     api.py
  main.py
```

my **init**.py looks like the following

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_cors import CORS

api = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix="/api")
cors = CORS()
cors.init_app(api, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*", "supports_credentials": True}})
```

and my main.py

```
def setup_app_config(app):
    database_uri = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}?sslmode={sslmode}'.format(
            user=os.getenv('PGUSER'),
            password=os.getenv("PGPASSWORD"), 
            host=os.getenv("PGHOST"), 
            port=os.getenv("PGPORT"), 
            database=os.getenv("PGDATABASE"),
            sslmode=os.getenv("PG_SSL")
        )
    
    app.config.update(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=database_uri,
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
    )
    CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}},  supports_credentials=True)

app = Flask(__name__)

setup_app_config(app)
db.init_app(app)

app.register_blueprint(api, urlprefix="/")
```

I keep getting the following error on browser console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
xhr.js?b50d:160 POST http://localhost:8000/api/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

On my axios config I am using the following flags `withCredentials: true`. Any tips on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a couple of links that might help you - https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/ ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955973/issue-with-flask-cors-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all cors-related code from `__init__.py`, only leave CORS initialization in your `setup_app_config`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but it was actually what I did and got it working.