# Problems cors in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

I am trying to consume a payment gateway API, with react, I am using `useParams()` and I get the following cors error how can I solve it?

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://khipu.com/api/2.0/payments' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
```

I tried to put a proxy in the package.json, but it did not work, I am in a development environment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sadly your question does not meet the community guidelines. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298478/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesn-t-pass-acce)?

I think you may need to use the

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

I hope this helps :D