# Enable CORS policy IN OData Service

Tags: ajax, cors, odata, sap-gateway

The below error is shown when I hit this OData API with simple HTML page from jQuery AJAX call already set all header even enable CORS from front end but still giving me this error where I enable this CORS policy in OData.

I created simple HTML page with AJAX request function in which I want to hit this OData service to get response.

Error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://x.x.x.xxx:xxxx/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZFI_M_SRV_01/ZFI_MSet' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
>
> [image: corserror]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298478/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesn-t-pass-acce) related post?

Comment: Yes my problem is in sap odata service how can i enable cors in odata sap, not in asp.net web api