# views CORS error, but you get data and it is visible C# (ASP .Net Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this configuration in my `Startup` method, apparently everything works fine

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000",  
                                               "http://localhost:3000",
                                               "http://localhost:3001")
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .WithMethods("PUT", "GET"));
        });


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

But when I start to do tests with another url that is not registered, the request shows a cors error but at the same time the response is shown, so does it mean that I run my services without being registered?

In this screenshot, you can see the url to which I make a request

[image: image here]

What is the right thing to do to secure my API? I have also read that browsers will always execute requests even if it is not visible

> [CORS error, but data is fetched regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737291/cors-error-but-data-is-fetched-regardless)

Thank you very much for reading me, I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firdtly,the url is `http://localhost:44344`,so you need to add it into `WithOrigins`.And you need to make sure the method type of the request is including in `WithMethods("PUT", "GET")`.Also,you'd better put `app.UseCors("MyPolicy");` between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000",  
                                               "http://localhost:3000",
                                               "http://localhost:3001",
                                               "http://localhost:44344")
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .WithMethods("PUT", "GET"));
        });


app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

the dot.net code in Configure and ConfigureService is correct. try allow any method and remove with origins. see if you can hit the endpoint with postman

```
 options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case browser will always execute the request, this is how it works.

As an option apart from CORS you can add host filtering. Just add semicolon-delimited list of host names into your `appsettings.json`

```
{
  ...

  "AllowedHosts": "example1.com;example2.com;localhost"
}
```

See [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hostfiltering.hostfilteringoptions.allowedhosts?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for details

---

Also starting from ASP.NET Core 5 `Kestrel` server supports host filtering as well - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/host-filtering?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: thank you very much, it's new to me!!!