# Why am I getting CORS error when API return data without crashing app

Tags: next.js, cors, bigcommerce, react-query, static-site-generation

I am starting with the Nextjs app and BigCommerce API.

I start testing the best ways to fetch data, and currently, I am testing react-query with SSG.

I am not sure why am I getting a CORS error when data is returned.
Data is returned before the error.

Home page:

```
export default function Home(props: { data: any }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <List />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: () => fetchPosts(),
  });

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  };
}
```

API config :

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const fetchPosts = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/alw7i94qb0/v3/catalog/products`, {
    headers: {
      //   "X-Auth-Client": process.env.BIGCOMMERCE_STORE_API_CLIENT_ID,
      "X-Auth-Token": process.env.BIGCOMMERCE_STORE_API_TOKEN,
    },
  });
  return { data };
};

const usePosts = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: () => fetchPosts(),
  });
};

export { usePosts, fetchPosts };
```

List component:

```
const List = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = usePosts();
  console.log(data?.data.data);
  return <div>{data?.data.data[0].name}</div>;
};
```

And this is the error I am getting in the console:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/alw7i94qb0/v3/catalog/products' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

**NOTE** API returns data normally and app works without crashing

Comment: Looks like bigcommerce doesn't support CORS and calling its api from browser. Call from serverside. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942398/6212530

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error, but data is fetched regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737291/cors-error-but-data-is-fetched-regardless)